# Rails 4 appending query/inspect/debug info after for/each loop for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, associations, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app that is doing a really weird thing.

I have 2 models with a `has_many` association: `Group` `has_many :members`. (A `Member` can only belong to one `Group`.) So I try to list the members of a group as such:

```
<ul>
  <%= for member in @group.members do %>
    <li class="entry">
      <%= link_to member.name, member_path(member) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Simple enough; it's the same logic I used to list all groups, in the group index, and it works fine. However, this is the HTML output:

```
<ul>

    <li class="entry">
      <a href="/members/23">John Doe</a>
    </li>

    <li class="entry">
      <a href="/members/25">Jane Doe</a>
    </li>
[#&lt;Member id: 23, name: &quot;John Doe&quot;, [timestamps], group_id: 3&gt;, #&lt;Member id: 25, name: &quot;Jane Doe&quot;, [timestamps], group_id: 3&gt;]</ul>
```

What the hell? I have no `inspect` or `debug` call anywhere in my views, and yet it keeps appending the entire query after the loop. The same happens with the `each` iterator.

It's maybe worth noting that the `Member` model also has a `has_many :through` association with another model, `Seminar`, (`:through => :memberships`). I iterate through the association in the same way and the same happens.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `ERB` tags:

```
<% for member in @group.members do %>
```

Not:

```
<%= for member in @group.members do %>
```